# Pour over coffee is too bland or too acid

Tags: pour-over, v60, acid

I buy coffee from local roaster and when I make it in two mins, pour over with v60, it gets too acid. If I make it in 2:45 it gets too bland. My other settings are the same.

3 seconds off boil. 17-18 grams coffee per 250ml of water. Washed filter, pre infused for 40 seconds, dripped in spiral form.

I fear that the roaster is not worth the effort but it's the only local roaster I know. They leave the roasted coffee in a pot for 2 days and they put it in a bag with valve only when you buy it.

What should I try to give this coffee a chance?

Comment: it sounds undrerroasted. Acidity and other distinct tastes, if not defected, is a good potential if the roast was taken a bit futher ahead. If your roaster is picking up lessons from the "early" Third Wave period, then they must still be gung-ho on the light roast, which was a problem for the industry, which piqued a lot of people MOSTLY because of the aesthetic.

Comment: It has lighter color than others but I guess it's filtered coffee specialised roasted. I got today another coffee from a big brand from mainlands and I am super happy from the first try. I guess I will ditch them. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Do you grind at home and if yes what kind of grinder do you use? Also I'd suggest to wait a bit longer before pouring so the water can cool down to in between 92 and 95 degrees. It'll probably take 30s or so. And you could also try to start pouring at around 30s into the bloom. For me 30s bloom gives the best results.

Comment: @avocado1 Fiorenzato nano f4e. With this coffee the bloom takes longer this is why i wait 40s. It's fresh roasted, about 4-5 days, maybe it's for that. I gave up with this coffe, I now use another blend comming from Athens. It's so much better. I can play between red fruits with milk chocolate and nuts with dark chocolate!

Comment: Is the other coffee from Athens from TAF by the way? If yes, enjoy, they are really great ;)

Comment: It's a Taresso coffee, from Korithnos I think.It's really great but it takes ages to come.

Comment: "They leave the roasted coffee in a pot for 2 days"
  
This is called degassing and is a vital step, without it your coffee would taste burnt.

Comment: @technical_difficulty Yes, I understand that now. The do have great coffee afterall. I was me the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the main thing you're not carefully controlling for is **temperature**.  I have found that if I use cooler temperatures (80-92 degrees celsius) for my pour-over, I get very bright/acidic tones.  Hotter water (92-100 degrees celsius) always gives me more bitterness and earthy flavors.  I use an electric kettle with a thermometer to maintain the temperature accurately so I can keep a temperature in the middle, in order to get both sets of flavors.  I would guess that by 2:45, your water is too cool and you're just extracting the acidic notes.  Try keeping your water hotter (and measure to see what temperature you're using).

I might also suggest giving your coffee a nice 60 second bloom time (pour enough water over them to get them wet, then wait for the gas to escape).  That helps you extract everything (complex and bitter notes included) from the grounds.

You could also consider letting your coffee age a bit longer.  Sometimes, beans are best 7+ days after roasting.

Good luck!